# Unformatted output when printing a SOAP message with StreamResult or after modfiying its DOM structure

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, formatting

I´d like to output the content of a some `SOAPMessage` (a request and a response in this case), let´s say to the standard output, and I am having issues to see the content in a well-formatted way:

```
// Create the Message
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage msg = mf.createMessage();

// In my case I get the content from a known well XML file (which is well formatted, BTW)
SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();
StreamSource prepMsg = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(targetFile));
sp.setContent(prepMsg);

// Add some info, save changes and send to output
SOAPElement soapHeaderElem = msg.getSOAPHeader().addChildElement("header", "","xmlapi_1.0");
SOAPElement securityHeaderElem = soapHeaderElem.addChildElement("security");
SOAPElement userHeaderElem = securityHeaderElem.addChildElement("user");
userHeaderElem.setValue(user);
SOAPElement passHeaderElem = securityHeaderElem.addChildElement("password");
passHeaderElem.addAttribute(new QName("hashed"), String.valueOf(hashedPassword));
passHeaderElem.setValue(password);

msg.saveChanges();
msg.writeTo(System.out);
```

Here, the only part that is well formatted is the part loaded from the XML, the rest is displayed in a single line!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Header>
    <header xmlns="xmlapi_1.0"><security><user>****</user><password hashed="false">****</password></security></header></SOAP:Header>        
    <SOAP:Body>
     </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

On the other hand, when I inspect the body of the response using a `DomSource`and a `StreamResult` the content of the message is displayed in a single line (all of it):

```
SOAPMessage rp = soapConnection.call(msg, remoteURL);
// Iterate
Source sc = new DOMSource(rp.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody().getChildNodes().item(i));

// And for each...
TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer tf = tff.newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
```

My questions are:

- Is there any property I set to those objects to have a well formatted output in any of the cases? (Something similar to the JAXB `Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` property)?
- Is there a way to force a reformat of the message being sent?
- Do you have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out that by using these properties in the Transformer object, you can get a well indented output:

```
TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer tf = tff.newTransformer();
// Set formatting
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
Source sc = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getContent();

OutputStream streamOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(changeFileFolder, "soapRequest.xml"));
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(streamOut);
tf.transform(sc, result);
```